# support unicode in magento product url key

Tags: magento

I would like to use my language (not english) for url key. I research and found there're some tutorial on : http://rakan.me/2012/07/19/support-unicode-in-magento-product-url-key/ but it show 404 not found already.

anyway someone give this link to download: https://github.com/Minglong/Magento-unicode-URL
but in this zip file it contains only module folder(Model and etc). so I think I need to write the rest myself. Please advice me how can I implement this module.

Or anyone ever try this module, is it working ? 
Thks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the code from GITHUB is fine. You just need to add the below code at `app/etc/modules/Rakanalh_UnicodeUrls.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Rakanalh_UnicodeUrls>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Rakanalh_UnicodeUrls>
</modules>
</config>
```

If you place the above code from github in `local` folder then the `codePool` tag has to be `local` or else if you place it in `community` folder then `codePool` tag has to be `community`.